# Getting HTTP 401 Unauthorized error while trying to call Lists.asmx

Tags: 2007, web-services, windows-application, windows-server

I am facing this weired issue while trying to call the GetList method of the Lists.asmx web serice from my local dev box. Everything works fine as long as I pass default credentials

```
listProxy.Credentials = System.Net.CrderntialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

But things go wrong as soon as I pass my credentials:

```
listProxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("devbox\testuser", "password");
```

or

```
listProxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("testuser", "password","devbox");
```

Note: I have added testuser in the Site Owners group on target SharePoint site collection.

My Development Machine Configuration:

1. Win2k3 SP2
2. No AD installed - **devbox** is the machine name.
3. Standalone MOSS Installation
4. VS2008

I even tried disabling the loopbackcheck by adding this entry to the registry **disableloopbackcheck 1**

What can be the possible issue?

Comment: Yes I am able to login using devbox\testuser via browser.

Comment: Isn't `\t` in the 2nd snippet treated as an escape sequence? Try to use `"devbox\\testuser"` or `@"devbox\testuser"` instead.

Comment: If you're able to login as the test user, try to manually load Lists.asmx whilst logged in, and also double check that you can navigate the List you want to interrogate whilst logged in too.

Comment: James can you please re-explain "try to manually load Lists.asmx"

Comment: I guess he meant you should try to navigate to **http://<site>/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx**.

Comment: is your DEV machine x64 AMD64 or x86?? 
what is the Sharepoint version 64 but or 32 bit??

I faced the same issue, there was some issue with security dll. I think I either copied the x86 dll and compiled it in 32 bit to test.

Comment: open the IIS logs to determine which kind of 401 error it is. It can be 401.1, 401.2, etc. which have different causes and resolutions. You have to get the status and substatus values in the log files to find it

Comment: I get the same error... Any better solution???

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue recently and it was because the security binding was incorrect in the app.config/web.config. For me it needed to be

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
</security>
```

rather than the default which was

```
<security mode="None">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

I was using VS2010, not sure if that is relevant but my C# was slightly different to yours as well.

```
UserGroupService.UserGroupSoapClient client = new UserGroupService.UserGroupSoapClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
client.ClientCredentials.SupportInteractive = true;
System.Xml.Linq.XElement users = client.GetUserCollectionFromGroup(GroupName.Text);
ResponseXml.Text = users.ToString();
```